Cartoon show about a mammoth frozen in ice age, waking up in modern era
I have seen this English speaking color cartoon show show back in the 1990s.
The plot is told in the intro song. A giant mammoth is trapped in a block of ice which melts in our nowadays and the mammoth befriends a bunch of kids.
Each episode, he tells these kids a story about the days in which he had a human friend who was very smart and resourceful. 
In one episode, the mammoth tells them how his primitive human friend back in the ace age was able to invent hot shower system. First by making some sort of water transport from one area to another. Then he finds out that the water is not hot enough. Then he solves the problem but finds out that the flow of the water is not enough, etc.
I think the name of the show is the name of the human in the ace age, and it must rhyme with "Crow" or something like that.

You nearly answered your own question. It was called Cro, an animated 90s educational show.

Dr. C and Mike travel to the Arctic to study artifacts, and find a frozen woolly mammoth named Phil. They thaw it out, and are surprised to find that it can speak. Whenever a situation involves physics principles, Phil remembers when a similar situation occurred long ago in Woollyville with his fellow mammoths and his Cro-Magnon friend Cro who lives with a family of Neanderthals. Each episode runs through how the situation was resolved through simple engineering.

It originally ran on ABC. Here's the intro:




Wow. It is indeed this one. To think I was very close to answer my own question. Thanks as always.
